# MVC User log in and sessions

Tags: model-view-controller, session, cookies

My web application requires a user to be logged in to view any webpage on it.

When a user logs in I store, in sessions, their username and password for retrieval later on. This all works fine but, if I rerun my project it seems to skip past authentication and go straight to the controller for that action.

What I presume is happening is that `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);` is remembering that the user is logged in but my sessions aren't updated.

How can I trap this scenario and update my sessions accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of going about it.

First, you can choose, not to persist the cookie. But this will still cause the exception if the session has not expired and you recompile your project. Recompiling the project destroys the session state.

Though putting the password in session state is not the preferred way of going about it, I am sure you would have a valid reason of doing it that way.

However, if you want to do it that way, you can override the Application_AuthenticateRequest event in Global.asax. This event fires every time a request comes in and you can check if the request is authenticated (using HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) and repopulate the session state.

By the way, can you elaborate why you need to store the user password in session state?

Comment: I communicate to a WCF service with username/password message encryption which is why I need to know the username and password; it is used on every call to the WCF service - if there is a better way to do this please let me know

Comment: One way of doing it would be to maintain a session in WCF, though that itself is not recommended :). Though I was in the same scenario once and the business dictated us not to save the password in the session state and we created a "universal" password for all and passed that along once we knew that the user was authenticated in our web application. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Thanks Imran - currently our WCF services is also our MemberShip and RoleProvider so all authentication is done via that

Comment: I believe you can still do the same. Only supply the password to the login WCF method, and for rest of the communication, just use a universal password. Though if you are not pressed to not using session state to store passwords, probably it's not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

If I am correctly understood the issue,you can have base action class so and move the authentication mechanism there.So for every request this base will be invoked so you can make sure that the authentication mechanism is not skipped.